# Open cart Remove $width And $height

Tags: php, opencart

I use open cart I am trying to get on my slideshow controller remove the `$width` and `$height`.

And just get the image, title, and link. I have tried to remove the `$widths` and `$height` but still get error

```
<?php  
class ControllerModuleSlideshow extends Controller {
    public function index($setting) {
    static $module = 0;

    $this->load->model('design/banner');
    $this->load->model('tool/image');

    $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/flexslider/flexslider.css');
    $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js');

    $data['width'] = $setting['width']; //need to remove
    $data['height'] = $setting['height']; //need to remove

    $data['banners'] = array();

    $results = $this->model_design_banner->getBanner($setting['banner_id']);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $result['image'])) {
            $data['banners'][] = array(
                'title' => $result['title'],
                'link'  => $result['link'],
                'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['width']//need to remove, $setting['height']//need to remove)
            );
        }
    }

    $data['module'] = $module++;

    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/slideshow.tpl')) {
        return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/slideshow.tpl', $data);
    } else {
        return $this->load->view('default/template/module/slideshow.tpl', $data);
    }
}
}
```

Can't seem to find the way to make this work in replace of the width and height

```
public function getImage($image){
$image = DIR_IMAGE . $image;

if($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
    return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $image;
} else {
    return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $image;
}   
}

$this->getImage($result['image']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact problem not too long ago. It was driving me daft and I all I wanted was to make the slide show responsive but the W x H values were becoming very troublesome to remove without affecting other classes. **Portability was also a serious concern of mine**. Basically all this is doing is riding off the nivoslider code but using the bootstrap carousel for the display. So you could change the slideshow banners as you always have, and they are always displayed on the front end.

If you happen to be using the bootstrap 3 framework, this is a great work around which proved successful. Don't edit the slideshow.php, edit **slideshow.tpl** instead. I highly don't recommend you mess with the php files unless you are very comfortable with php and the idea of mvc in opencart. To be honest, you probably should never edit, just extend or start from scratch as it uses fall back mechanisms.

But anyway, the code:

```
<div class="col-md-12" >
    <div id="homepage" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php 
              $flag = 0;
              foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
              <div class="item <?=$flag==0?"active":""?>">

              <?php if ($banner['link']) { ?>
              <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a>
               </div>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" />
              </div>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php 
              $flag=1; 
              } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

...and the JQuery

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
          });
        });
  </script>
```

**edits welcomed**

Answer (score 0):

Width and Height are the feature which will help you to assign width and height dynamically that you can set from the admin panel

```
admin>extensions>modules>slideshow[edit]
```

if you don't want this feature in effect

Simply go to the template file

find (catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/slideshow.tpl)

```
<div id="slideshow<?php echo $module; ?>" class="nivoSlider" style="width: <?php echo $width; ?>px; height: <?php echo $height; ?>px;">
```

Replace with

```
<div id="slideshow<?php echo $module; ?>" class="nivoSlider">
```

Comment: As I have said to many people I do not want to use admin panel resize its a pain getting tired people tell me to use admin panel resizing open cart 2 does not use nivo slider I prefer to do my image resize by css I get better mobile responsive that way.

Comment: then as i explained above if you dont want these feature just go to the template file and modify according to whatever you want

Comment: I have all ready tried these ways I have decided to remove the modules and make my own I have also removed the width and height from the modules in the admin area.

Answer (score 0):

two ways to help u :)
in catalog/controller/module/slideshow.php

BEFORE

```
$this->data['width'] = $setting['width'];
$this->data['height'] = $setting['height'];
```

AFTER

```
 $this->data['width'] = '0';  // or NULL 
 $this->data['height'] = '0'; // or NULL
```

in catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/slideshow.tpl

BEFORE

```
<div id="slideshow<?php echo $module; ?>" class="nivoSlider" style="width: <?php echo $width; ?>px; height: <?php echo $height; ?>px;">
```

AFTER

```
<div id="slideshow<?php echo $module; ?>" class="nivoSlider">
```

if you need to add custom height and width add this to above code change 000 to you size

```
 <div id="slideshow<?php echo $module; ?>" class="nivoSlider" style="width: 000px; height: 000px;">
```

Comment: I am using open cart 2.0 as base frame work. I have removed the width and height from admin all ready. Open Cart 2.0 Master does not use Nivo Slider. I might just delete these modules I think is best not doing way I am after. I do not want to change image sizes in admin that's why removed it in admin modules. To get better responsiveness for bootstrap its better to do it via css image sizes from my experience.

Comment: you right OC 2.0 uses  class="flexslider" so need of width & height bcz of responsiveness for bootstrap

Comment: Yeah but as I said I have removed all the admin resize inputs because want to do image sizes in css better for responsiveness rather than admin All the people are the same they will not change keep on saying use admin resize but I don't want to tired of talking about it now. And people don't realize that to have images show up need resizing module what I am trying to do it get rid of resizing module but still have in controller a function that will pick up module that I could work with the controller slideshow datat array.